# getting an onclick event to a select option using js

Tags: javascript, html, select

i am having a very frustrating problem. I have this code
which filters out my results and inputs them into a select box

```
var syn = <?=json_encode($syn)?>;
function filterByCity() {
        var e = document.getElementById("city_filter");
        var city = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        var selectOptions = document.getElementById('syn_list');
        selectOptions.options.length = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < syn.length; i++) {
            if (city == syn[i]['city'] || city == 'all') {
                selectOptions.options[selectOptions.options.length] = new Option(syn[i]['name'], syn[i]['id'] + '" onclick="updateTxtContent(\'' + syn[i]['id'] + '\')');
            }
        }
    }
```

as you might see i am adding a onclick listener to every select "option" which look great in the source code of the page itself but if i copy it into an edit i notice this
my problem is that the "updateTxtContent()" function is not called.

```
<select size="10" name="syn_list" id="syn_list" class="span12" dir="rtl" style="text-align:right;">
<option value="13&quot; onclick=&quot;updateTxtContent('13')">option a</option>
<option value="14&quot; onclick=&quot;updateTxtContent('14')">option b</option>
```

obviously there should be a better way to do this that i am not aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to have your event handler on your select rather than on the option.  See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G7uQZ/) for what I mean

```
<select size="10" name="syn_list" id="syn_list" class="span12" dir="rtl" style="text-align:right;" onchange="updateTxtContent();">
<option value="13">option a</option>
<option value="14">option b</option>
</select>

<script>
function updateTxtContent(){
 alert($("#syn_list").val());   
}   
</script>
​
```

Or since it looks like you aren't using jQuery:

```
function updateTxtContent(){
    var e = document.getElementById("syn_list");
    var f = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;    
    alert(f);
}
```

Comment: You could even pass `this` as a parameter to the function, and then just use `this.value`...just to avoid the `getElementById`

Comment: yea well this does not really answer my question but it did make the entire thing work so thank you very much. you and MikeB

Answer (score 3):

maybe try an onchange event in your select tag.

```
<select size="10" name="syn_list" id="syn_list" class="span12" dir="rtl" style="text-align:right;" onchange='updateTxtContext(this.value);'>
```

Comment: this worked for me when my 'id' was of the form 'flow.groupA01s[0].address'

Answer (score 0):

option elements can not have click events in most browsers.

And new option is setting the value and the text, not sure why you think you can set other attributes with it.

You want to use a change event on the select element.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2016 it looks like click events are supported for selects and have the option clicked upon as target:

using jQuery

```
click_handler = function(e) {
    alert('clicked on: ' + e.target.value);
}

$('#syn_list').click(click_handler);
```

Works at least in Firefox 44