# JS - Onclick handler for dynamically added options in select

Tags: javascript

Been searching for a couple days and this is driving me bonkers. 
I am a semi-novice when it comes to JS so forgive the ugly scripting below.

I have a form where I'm selecting one option, then depending on that selection it dictates the following available answers.

Example and goal : 
Choose Country : Canada (working) <-onclick=function() to fill province select box
Choose Province: Ontario (working) <-dynamically added options, onclick=function() to add options to county is where the issue lies. I cannot add specific onclick functions to each item in option list. 
Choose County:

```
function Province()
{
    var Province= document.getElementById("prov");
    Province.hidden = false; //unhiding the province box
    Province.options[Province.options.length] = new Option('Ontario', 'ont'); 
    Province.options[Province.options.length] = new Option('Manitoba', 'man');
        onchange = function()
        {
            var County= document.getElementById("county");
            County.hidden = false; // unhiding the county box
            Province.disabled = true; //disabling the province box
        }
 }
```

Right after it says new option I would like to add .onclick( cityfunction() ) but that doesn't work. 
Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. (I am aware I could have used an easier way to add elements to my list - again, rookie thing). If the .add works with the onclick event I will happily flip over.

Comment: Any chance you can create a jsFiddle for us to use?

Comment: Well you cant onclick for options not in on normal select -> options

Comment: What is this `onchange` global variable?

Comment: Haven't tried making a jsFiddle before but I'll see what I can do.

Comment: onchange is just using the js built in function so that what there is a change on the select it automatically unhides the county select box and disables the province select box.

Comment: Your question is not clear, or at least not easy to read! For example: "Right after it says new option I would like to add .onclick( cityfunction() ) ". What do you mean "add .onclick"? Add to what? And what do you mean "it says new option"? Are we supposed to guess what you're looking at?
As someone else said, a jsFiddle would be great! Just trying to help here, no offense meant.

Comment: @rolf I'm working on the jsFiddle. What I meant is that I would like to add an onclick handler to the dynamically added content. I can't seem to add anything to the dynamically added content. I want it so that once you click the province (dynamically added content) it goes to the next function which dynamically adds the counties. Is that any clearer? (and no offense taken)

Comment: jsFiddle doesn't seem to like my dom manipulation (hiding, unhiding, disabling and re-enabling). I'm wondering if I just have the wrong framework chosen.

Comment: It shouldn't be complicated to add an onclick handler to dynamic data. I'm gonna try to propose something as an answer. What I was complaining about is that I can't seem to understand well what you are describing and what is happening in your code.

Comment: PS: Yes it's clearer :)

Comment: Hey guys I appreciate all of your help. Turns out it seems to be something as simple as passing the value into the onchange event. So it should be **onchange = function (value)**

Answer (score 0):

Well you cant bind onclick for option and take it's value, at least not for the normal select -> options.

you have several options: 1.get an outside library that creates a fake select and the options are `<li>`s.

2.do on change and create a class with keys -> values that can be added dynamically. and then on change -> take the value and deal with the class.

I personally like http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/ its nice.

However if you perfect the more complicated way:

```
onChangeClass = function(){
    this.options = [
          {"value" : "something", actionToTake: function(){/* ....  */}}
    ];
    this.doCall = function(selected){
         $.each(this.options,function(index,value){
              if(selected == value.value){
                   value.actionToTake();
              }
         });
    }
}

 var somVar = new onChangeClass ();
 somVar.options.push({"value" : "something2", actionToTake: function(){/* ....  */}});
 somVar.doCall();
```

Comment: This uses jQuery (doesn't it?). We don't know if jQuery is available here.

Answer (score 0):

To add an onclick handler to dynamically added content, something like this should usually work:

```
Province.options[Province.options.length] = new Option('Manitoba', 'man');
Province.options[Province.options.length].onclick = function(e) {
     // event handling code here
}
```

But as someone already mentioned, and I vaguely remember running into such a problem myself; it might be possible that it would be impossible to add an onclick event handlers on an option element inside an HTML select element. A search brings up similar problems...

In this case what I'd do is try to bind a handler to the select onchange event (onclick on the select element might work too...). `Province.onchange = function(e){}` and inside that, you can access variables such as the currently selected option... It does make things more complicated.

Here is a seemingly similar question on stackoverflow:
[getting an onclick event to a select option using js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12808706/getting-an-onclick-event-to-a-select-option-using-js)

This is a small library that attempts to provide a workaround:
http://code.google.com/p/expandselect/

Searching for **html select option onclick** (on Google) will bring up other similar questions.

Hoping that helps...