# How to set dropdown selection to localStorage?

Tags: reactjs

I have a dropdown component where I am trying to set a localStorage value to the option that is selected from the dropdown.

```
const [userLanguage, setUserLanguage] = useState('en');
useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem("userLanguage", userLanguage ? userLanguage : '')
}, [userLanguage]);

return (
  <select>
    <option onClick={?}>one</option>
    <option onClick={?}>two</option>
  </select>
);
```

I am really confused on how to handle the onClick event that would set the selected option the the localStorage.

I have been able to find solutions that are somewhat related, but not that show examples for React, and specifically using hooks.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: I would think it would just be `onClick={() => setUserLanguage('one')}` or whatever language "one" is supposed to represent. Typically, however, one would bind to the `change` event of the `select` and use the `value` of the select, as in https://stackoverflow.com/q/47850489/215552

Comment: ok, i just tried that, it's not updating the localStorage value. I have tried so many options, and nothing seems to work

Comment: Yeah, binding to `onClick` of the `option` doesn't work. Use `onChange={(e) => setUserLanguage(e.target.value)}` on the `select`.

Comment: omg thank you! if you want the points for the correct answer, could you submit that as the answer and i will mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would bind to the `onChange` event listener instead. The click event of `option` elements in single-select `select` elements is notoriously fragile. In your case, change your code to something like:

```
const [userLanguage, setUserLanguage] = useState('en');
useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem("userLanguage", userLanguage ? userLanguage : '')
}, [userLanguage]);

return (
  <select onChange={(e) => setUserLanguage(e.target.value)}>
    <option value="one">one</option>
    <option value="two">two</option>
  </select>
);
```

I added `value` attributes to your `option`s only in an abundance of caution; by default the value of the `select` will gain the text of the `option` if the `value` is not explicitly set.

I should point out that older questions have pointed out the fragility of the `click` event on `option` elements. In particular, the answers to the question [getting an onclick event to a select option using js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12808706/215552) by [Vad.Gut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1304892/vad-gut) explain the situation well.